# How to use Sharepoint as a filserver against external programs

Tags: document-library, folder, office, external-data

I am workig for a survey company and we are starting to implement sharepoint as a fileserver.

The idea is that the surveyours working in the field uploads there measerud files to the file library and applies the approprite metadata.

Then people in the office are going to use this files in programs outside SP.

My problem is when syncing files to sharepoint localy the metadata does not appear in Windows, and therefor is very difficult for the staff at the office to know wich files they should be working on.

I tried adding folders to the document library so the people at the office can move the files they are going to work on in there and then opened that folder as an external hardrive in windows.

The problem with this is when i apply filters the folders dissapers.

My question is, how does people solved the problem with using extarnal programs together with Sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

1. Make site columns to use as your metadata fields
2. Add site columns to content types for all documents you want to have
3. Add content types to document library and turn content types on
4. Make the document templates use the SharePoint values

There is a lot of work required to build this.

Comment: But this would only work if the field users are creating a file based on templates in the library? or have i misunderstood your explanation.

Comment: no that is correct. the field users would have to use the templates from within SharePoint. i dont know if any 3rd party programs exist that can hook into SharePoint directly.